# searching for word defining something deep, elemental, symbolic, essential

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context

...they do talk but they talk slowly and quietly and not very often and say, not only what is SIGNIFICANT (???), but what is PRIME (???).

Comment: One of the senses of **quintessential** {adjective 1. _of the pure and essential essence of something_} [[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quintessential)] fits your title question but not your example (you need  ...'not that which is just significant, but rather that which ...').

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest "fundamental?" It harkens to the essential element(s) of something, the essence of its origin, the deep, historic beginning of it.